# SQL Server times out connections sometimes up to a few minutes after reboot of PC. Works fine after ~2-5mins

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have developed software that uses SQL Server and Entity Framework .NET to interface with it. After moving forward to SQL 2022 I noticed a new issue I had not seen in previous versions and I was wondering if anyone has any troubleshooting advice.

What happens is that if we reboot the W10 PC and have our software setup to start at boot, it throws SQL connection timeout errors and fails to run properly. This does not seem to be entirely consistent. I had two PC's that were doing that and setting SQL Agent and SQL Server Browser to autostart seemed to resolve that. But we have a handful of PC's where this does not occur. It also seems that SSMS cannot connect as well until a few minutes. After a few minutes have passed, without doing anything at all, it works entirely normally with all connections and queries working as intended. The PC's are modern HP Z series with high end multicore processors and 32GB of ddr4 ram and SSD's. I should not have a hardware bottleneck as far as I can tell.

Ideally what I am looking for is to configure SQL Server 2022 to work as immediately as possible after reboot instead of several minutes sometimes. We are experimenting and troubleshooting with some PC's but I am not super familiar with backend programming/configuration/troubleshooting of SQL Server itself. I would appreciate any advice to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Perhaps the service just doesn't start up as fast, due to whatever it's doing. You can check the sql server logs and compare the times when reboot is "done" and when it's ready to process incoming connections. As to how to fix it, perhaps you you can check if there's some service dependency it's waiting for to start

Comment: How big are your databases (specifically the transaction log files), how long is recovery time taking? Check the SQL Server Error log for more information on startup times.

Comment: Rebooting is never instantaneous. It is Windows, after all. How often are you rebooting and why are you doing this when people _notice_ the outage? How long it takes can depend on a lot of things, and aren't magically going to be fixed by upgrading to a slightly newer version of SQL Server or Windows. Things like extended memory checks (search for "enable quick boot"), database sizes, even features you're using (e.g. availability groups, accelerated database recovery), how many other services are starting up and competing for initialization resources (maybe set others to delayed start).

Comment: It's also not clear (at least to me) whether you are observing how much time the PC is spending shutting down, installing updates, posting, starting up Windows, configuring updates further, and finally being in a position of being able to log in. Or if you're just sitting on a remote machine "is it ready yet? how about now?" SQL Server isn't going to be able to be up and ready for incoming connections while that is all happening. But knowing how much time is spent on various parts of the entire reboot process can help you isolate what you can fix (and/or convince you to reboot less often).

Comment: @AaronBertrand In other words what I am saying is before SQL 2022 when I rebooted the windows PC, the boot would complete the desktop would load, the program would auto start then run and just be able to connect to SQL server right away. Now for some reason it takes sometimes several minutes after windows has completely booted and it has been sitting at the desktop idling. I might have to sift through what some of the other commenters are suggesting in the logs to see if there is something that is hanging it up a bit. I had no issues before so to be clear I didn't update to fix anything.

Comment: And what is the exact error message? Is it that a database is not accessible, or the server can't be found, or ...?

Comment: I'll echo what other commenters have said and say you should check SQL Server's ERRORLOG file (see the `-e` parameter in the service's start parameters) to see what it's doing. Probably it's spending a lot of time checking the transaction log files for incomplete transactions that need rollback, etc., which implies that you're either using the wrong recovery model or not taking full/diff/log backups frequently enough. While in the services area you could also check to make sure that it's set to "Automatic" instead of "Automatic (Delayed Start)" because that would just add even more delays.

Comment: A new version of SQL Server could easily take a bit longer to fire up... Or the service might be set to delayed start. Either way, as everyone has said, why reboot at a time that affects people? And why care about a couple of minutes?

Comment: If you have large queries which need to be rolled back you could look at accelerated database recovery. https://www.sqlshack.com/accelerated-database-recovery-instant-rollback-and-database-recovery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that SQL 2022 by default is configured as Automatic (Delayed) start now instead of just Automatic which means it starts after all the Automatic Services. Setting it to Automatic fixed it. Apologies as my post was apparently not clear enough for those that tried to help.

Comment: Can confirm that. We experienced the same problem when migrating some IIS .net sites from Win Server 2012 with an older MS SQL to Win Server 2022 with MS SQL 2022. After the migration the new sites could not connect to the DB on each restart. We found that the DB service was by default set to "Automatic (Delayed)" and waited about 3 minutes before firing up. The IIS service was set to "Automatic" and thus the sites started long before the DB came up.